# Confused to fix warning "Wasting Memory" at Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am confused to fix this problem :

```
[WARN] :   linker: libtiverify.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
[WARN] :   V8Object: Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
```

someOne has same problem ? or that is issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The 'text relocations' errors occur due to a bug in the android NDK that has since been fixed in r8c.

[Refer this link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23203)

Comment: I am working with titanium to develop android app first.
actually. in my computer I did not install the NDK.
should I install the NDK first to fix this bug ?

Comment: I had install NDK, by following this docs : http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_NDK

but still not solved